# Probability and Statistics question on sequences and vowels

Tags: combinatorics

How many 4-letter “words” (sequences of letters with repetitions allowed) in which vowels appear only
(if at all) as the first and last letter?

please answer as soon as you can, really appreciate it!!

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? And why are you un a hurry?

Comment: I have another summer class that starts soon and want to understand this problem before I start it. So far I have gotten 26^4*3^2 which gave me 4,112,784 as my answer but I have no way to check if I am correct. This is using the vowels a,e,i,o,u

Comment: How do you find this answer? Also, you should include your tries in tu your post, not in the comments.

Comment: Right answer is $26^2\times21^2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to calculating the number of 4 letter words with no vowels in positions 2,3. This gives $26^2\cdot 21^2$ because all letters are valid is the 1st and 4th positions.

Comment: Very good answer! I was surprised that it was this simple to calculate.